# Loop conditional and exit work in linear and binary search

Tags: c, exit

> 25    6   C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Dev C++\binary.c  [Warning] incompatible
>   implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'

I am using Dev c++ and here as you can see it says:

> incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'

I really fed up of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The `exit` function is defined in `stdlib.h` library.

Then you need to add this `#include <stdlib.h>` line to your  program